# Why does Visual Studio keeps running an old project?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I had an old project I was working on previously, just to keep it simple let's say the project is a calculator.

Today, I opened Visual Studio, selected a new project, and add a source file *`helloworld.c`*. If I leave the whole file empty and press f5 (start debugging), it gives me the error there is no entry point, which is expected.

However, once I add in the code for helloworld.c and try to start debugging, I get an error about multiple instance of "main". So then I remove the main from helloworld.c and try pressing start debugging again, and now for some reason it runs my calculator program. I have no idea why is this is happening. I don't have the old program running at all and I haven't touched it, how can I stop Visual Studio from running this project??

Thanks

Edit: seems like this only happens when I have "#include <'winsock2.h>", but im not sure why this would be related... (ignore the ')

Comment: Have you selected *Set As Startup Project* ??

Comment: yes i have, i've even tried right clicking the solution and compiling, there is only the single helloworld.c in my source files for this solution

Comment: close the old project, the open the new project.  If VS is executing the old project, then the old project has not been closed